# Is there tiered pricing for customizable options?

Tags: magento2, tiered-pricing, customizable-options

One of my customizable options has values that charge extra. Say, when a user chooses "Red" from the "Color" dropdown, it'll add $0.10 to the product (e.g. a shirt).

Now, when the user buys 20 of these shirts, instead of having $0.10 added on for each, I want $0.05 added on for each.

This is basically tiered pricing, but instead of applying this to the product it's applied to the customizable option.

Is this possible in Magento 2? If not, is there an external solution, like a module, to do this?